# How to create bootable USB drive from DVD

Tags: fedora, usb-drive

I have a DVD with fedora 20 in it. My DVD drive doesn't work so I need to boot from an USB. I have copied the contents of the DVD into a USB drive and now how can I make this drive bootable?

Answer (score 0):

If the drive is able to be booted at all, that is if you successfully copied the right data to it, then you shouldn't need to do anything other than to actually boot to it (from the BIOS or UEFI as the case may be).

Comment: I copied the entire disk into the USB but it doesn't boot

Answer (score 0):

Just copying the DVD contents over is not enough to make the USB stick a bootable device. You need to run it through an App like UNetbootin[1](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net). It will even download the ISO image for you or you can also provide your own.

Comment: See Boogy's answer. That does work fine.

Comment: @vonbrand: I'm afraid that's incorrect. First the syntax[1] is reversed, if you want to read an ISO image and write it to a USB stick, than the command should read something like: `dd if=/path/to/file.iso of=/dev/usb_device bs=1M`. Second, this only works if the ISO image is a Hybrid Disk Image[2] if it's a regular ISO image it won't work from a USB key. [1]: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html - [2]: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with the **dd** command:

```
dd if=/dev/usb_key of=/pyth/to/mydvd.iso
```